# Partial commit using SELECT-INTO statement after the query failed

Tags: sql-server

I was testing possible issues with a query when the connection is lost or timed out. To do the test, I run a query with a fresh connection, and just seconds after I kill the program or disconnect the network. Then I check the impact of the query.

I believe that if a query, not within the explicit transaction fails for any reason, will roll back the effect. Of course, this makes sense for operations like DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE or DDL statements too. Implicit Transaction is OFF in the db.

My theory held true except when I ran a SELECT-INTO statement. Sample query that I tried -

```
SELECT * INTO test_table FROM audit
```

It failed due to Socket read timeout but later I found that even though there are no records inserted, the new table `test_table` was created as empty.

After browsing the docs for a while, according to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), it's expected behavior. That's understandable. But the problem for me is that I can't really retry this query execution as the table already exists.

I guess to fix this I need to use the explicit transaction around such statements.

To help me with the feature - Am I going the right way? And are there any other SQL statements that can cause similar behavior?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Since I got suggestions on how to fix this, I am wondering now if there are any other SQL statements that can cause similar behavior.

Comment: `SELECT INTO` is used to *create a new table* then perform an `INSERT`. Don't use `SELECT INTO` in the first place, except for *small* temporary tables. The new table needs modifications anyway, to add primary keys, indexes and constraints. It's better to create a staging table in advance, with the necessary indexes, and truncate it before/after using it

Comment: *"To help me with the feature - Am I going the right way?"* The documentation you linked to also explicitly tells you that that is the right direction if you need to use `INTO` and want every rolled back in the event of a failure: *" If you need the entire operation to succeed or fail as a whole, use an [explicit transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)."*

Comment: You either need use an explicit transaction or handle the eventuality like with drop table if exists. Does set xact_abort on impact at all?

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? You can't execute `SELECT * INTO test_table FROM audit` more than once

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that makes sense.

Comment: To explain a bit more, I am trying to work out a retry mechanism if a query fails with Socket errors. This of course will be generic and for all the SQL statements. So I was looking for problematic scenarios, such as this one.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of the latter part of the question? Are there any other similar statements that can cause issues if I try to rerun after a connection lost/error?

Comment: Sounds like, at least with a name like `test_table`, you should be using a temporary table (`#test_table`), @GautamKumarSamal . Then the temporary table will also be dropped if the connection is dropped, as the table only persists for the duration of the scope that created it.